# Facebook Instant Article RSS Feed Update

Tags: facebook, rss, blogger, instant, facebook-instant-articles

I added the Facebook instant article to my blog, which is a Blogger site. However, everytime Facebook pulls feeds from my RSS feed, its markup is completely wrong and I have to rearrange it every time.

For example,

**Here is one article pulled from RSS** - 
[image]

**And this is how my preferred markup is -**
[image]

How can I fix this and set this preferred markup as default?